# How to show data from SQL database in _Layout.cshtml in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, layout, partial-views

i am working on an **MVC OnlineShop project**, i made Category and products **database** in `SQL server`, now i want to show the categories from this database on the homepage of the web. I tried before creating a **session** and calling this **session** in the `_Layout.cshtml` , but i found that **session** is not a good idea to show categories on the homepage although it worked, because session is used mostly for cookies... 
***Question:*** is this the right way to do that, or any better idea to do so?
 i wrote this in my `Homecontroller.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

namespace MVCOnlineShop.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        OnlineStoreEntities storeDB = new OnlineStoreEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();
            return View(Categories);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Home/Browse
        public ActionResult Browse(string Category)
        {
            // Retrieve Category and its Associated Products from database
            var CategoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Products")
                .Single(g => g.CategoryName == Category);

            return View(CategoryModel);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Home/Details
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var Product = storeDB.Products.Find(id);

            return View(Product);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Home/Browse?Category=Games

    }
}
```

and made a ***PartialView*** in `Views/Home` called `CategoryLayout.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Categories";
}
<ul>
    @foreach (var Category in Model)
    {

        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName,
"Browse", new { Category = Category.CategoryName })
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

and wrote this in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">@Html.Partial("CategoryLayout")</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </ul>
                }
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: If the Categories are not going to change you could cache them in the application state, which is held server side. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-at-application-startup-cs

Comment: @Reshma i edited and added some codes please check

Comment: @BarryO'Kane categories could change later , so thats why i want to collect data from SQL server

Comment: The code you have is fine. I suspect that the categories will change very infrequently, so again I'd suggest storing them in the Application State if you want to cache them.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane , but i dont want static categories , yeah categories could not change later on , but maybe later i have to add a new catgery or something

Comment: Then just call them from the database.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane , yeah i did , just asking if this approach is good to show categories on the homepage

Comment: What happens if the user navigate from the homepage?

Comment: i am trying to show categories on the home page , and then when you hover over a category, you will see a drop down list of the products in such category @jamiedanq

Comment: @Ahmad if that's all you want to do then, i don't think it's a big deal loading it from the database. There are many ways to do that and that's definitely one of the ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

Edits

1. Create a Action method that returns a partial view

Don't use index to return partial view, since we need the partial view for asynchronous calls, write a new Action.

```
    public ActionResult GetCategories ()
    {
        var Categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();
        return PartialView("CategoryLayout",Categories );
    }
```

The above code will render the partial view with Categories model and will be sent back to the Layout View.

2. In the layout page Instead of

   ```
   @Html.Partial("CategoryLayout")
   ```

   Use

   ```
   @Html.RenderAction("GetCategories","Home")
   ```

Done!!!